# System.MissingMethodException: Method 'Array.Empty' not found with MvvmCross on Xamarin.Android

Tags: xamarin.android, azure-devops, mvvmcross, azure-pipelines, hockeyapp

I have an application that is working fine in Debug / Release mode but, as soon as I try to deploy it via HockeyApp and VSTS, I get the following error on startup:

```
System.MissingMethodException: Method 'Array.Empty' not found.
 at MvvmCross.Droid.Views.MvxActivityViewExtensions.OnViewCreate (IMvxAndroidView androidView, Android.OS.Bundle bundle) [0x00055] in <filename unknown>:0 
 at MvvmCross.Droid.Views.MvxActivityAdapter.EventSourceOnCreateCalled (System.Object sender, MvvmCross.Platform.Core.MvxValueEventArgs`1 eventArgs) [0x0000c] in <filename unknown>:0 
 at (wrapper delegate-invoke) System.EventHandler`1[MvvmCross.Platform.Core.MvxValueEventArgs`1[Android.OS.Bundle]]:invoke_void_object_TEventArgs (object,MvvmCross.Platform.Core.MvxValueEventArgs`1<Android.OS.Bundle>)
```

Also, I've noticed that if I try to use the following code:

```
var t = Array.Empty<object>();
```

VSTS is unable to compile my project, with the same error (`System.MissingMethodException: Method 'Array.Empty' not found.`)

Comment: Seems to be this ("solved") issue: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/issues/1363

Comment: Yes, looks like an issue with the Xamarin/Mono version of VSTS....